# Can somebody explain this C function?

Tags: c

I have some problems with this syntax. Could somebody explain to me what this C function is doing?

```
unsigned long protodec_henten(int from, int size, unsigned char *frame)
{
   int i = 0;
   unsigned long tmp = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     tmp |= (frame[from + i]) << (size - 1 - i);

   return tmp;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is this question about C syntax or the purpose of protodec_henten() ?

Comment: "Explain code"-questions are in general "stupid" hence that we don't know if he wants to know what a function is, what bitwise or is, or about the result of the function.

Comment: It's hard to determine the purpose of the function without an example call.  It could serve a bevy of different purposes (some esoteric, others fairly simple) depending on what frame contains.

Comment: Shouldn't "int size" be "size_t size" ?

Comment: @Tom, considering that size is used to influence a shift, it likely doesn't matter. Valid ranges are going to be small (looks like 1 - 33 on a 32-bit machine). You can pass invalid shift ranges either way. However, yes, it *should* be an unsigned type, but doesn't *have* to be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referring to the following line as the one with the confusing syntax.

```
tmp |= (frame[from + i]) << (size - 1 - i);
```

Lets break this down

- frame[from+i]: "from" represents an initial index into the array and i is simply the current offset.  So this is effectively iterating the array starting at index "from"
- size - 1 - i: This is calculating the number of bits to shift by and is doing so based on the current index.  This number will start at size -1 and will decrease as the loop progresses
- (frame[from+i] << (size - 1 - i): This shifts the value at from+i by the specified number of bits
- tpm |= ... : Dos a bitwise Or expression on the bytes that are still available once the iterated value has been shifted.

Comment: +1 you're the only one that explained in detail probably what he wanted

Comment: Isn't it shifting by the specified number of bits, not bytes?

Answer (score 7):

Others already described each line, so I'll just add what the function *does*. You can imagine bytes in `frame` between positions (`from`) and (`from+size`) on a "stack" with different position. First byte will be placed on the left.

```
bits from:      tmp: |    +  +     |(LSB-side of tmp)
frame[from]:           ---+----
frame[from+1]:          -----+--
frame[from+2]:           -+------
...
```

Now tmp has a bit set if any of the bytes "below" has a bit set in the related position.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bit-packer.  If, as Eric suggested, all chars in `frame` are either zero or one, then this will take `size` characters and pack their values into `tmp`.  For example, if `frame` (at offset `start`) contains the values `00 01 00 00 01 01 01 00`, then `protodec_henten(0,8,frame)` would return (leading zeroes omitted) 0x4E (or `01001110` in binary).  There are better ways to do this, so it may be doing something else, but it's hard to tell what.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Looks like a hashing function.</strike> On second thought this would make a pretty poor hash function.

They are shifting every frame by the remainder of the size and then ORing that with a static value. This value is then returned.

Comment: Just realized that it would be a crappy hashing function since eventually the value would get to 1111 1111.

Comment: Yeah, xor (^) is what you'd want for a hash function, not or (|).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't understand the `tmp |=` because this is probably the only part in the code that is "Hard" to understand. If you try search for C operators you will find a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), now `|=` means "Bitwise or", you can read more about them [here](http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/e4_bitwise_operators_and_or_xor.asp).

So what this code really does is that it takes some input, you tell the functon where to start reading in the "buffer"/"frame" and you do bitwise or on as many positions as the "size" parameter says.

Comment: | is bitwise OR, |= is bitwise OR assignment operator.

Comment: Yes well do i need to explain that = always assigns?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the bitwise OR, this function makes sense only if all values in `frame` are 0 or 1.

In this case, it will put `size` consecutive values (i.e. bits) of `frame` starting at index `from` into a single `unsigned long`. The last bit (at index `from+size-1`) will be inserted as least significant bit.

Answer (score -3):

This overall code is just copying a range of data into the tmp variable.  In fact, it is simply doing a memcpy the hard way.

Why not just do: memcpy(&tmp, frame+from, size)